# MongoDB - How to get data between start date and end date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is the MongoDB document.

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-24T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  },
  {
    name: "b",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-22T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  },
  {
    name: "c",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  }
]
```

I want to fetch all data based on the start date and end date.

I have tried with the following:

```
db.collection.find({
  start_date: {
    $gte: new Date()
  },
  end_date: {
    $lte: new Date()
  }
})
```

**Expected output**

If the current date is **2021-09-22**, then the output will be:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-24T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  },
  {
    name: "b",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-22T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  },

]
```

If the current date is **2021-09-23**, then the output will be:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    "start_date": ISODate("2021-09-21T12:13:34.151+05:30"),
    "end_date": ISODate("2021-09-24T12:13:34.000+05:30"),

  },

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$and` for multiple expression.

Note: `start_date` less than (`$lte`) current date and `end_date` greater than (`$gte`) current date so that current date is within the date range.

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      start_date: {
        $lte: new Date()
      }
    },
    {
      end_date: {
        $gte: new Date()
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wf-agXIas6z)

---

OR

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        $lte: [
          "$start_date",
          new Date()
        ]
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          "$end_date",
          new Date()
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fYGZBJQ0X9b)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But if the current date is `2021-09-21`, then all records should retrieve.

Comment: This is due to when new Date('2021-09-21'), without specific the time the datetime will be `2021-09-21T00:00:00Z`  which is not matched with any document.

Comment: How to achieve that too. I want to get those records also

Comment: Would say depend on your timezone. So for your test date do you specify the date as `new Date()` or `new Date('2021-09-21')`. As my side test, I am able to query the douments with the current date `new Date()`. I am in UTC+8 timezone.

Comment: I am in UTC+05:30 time zone. That could be the diff. Thank you @Yong Shun

Comment: You are welcome. And sorry that I give wrong info for the deleted comment just now.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly change the logic as mentioned below for the required output

```
db.collection.find({
  start_date: {
    $lte: new Date()
  },
  end_date: {
    $gte: new Date()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // With NodeJs
    Collection.find({
    $and: [
      {
        start_date: {
          $gte: new Date().toISOString(),
        },
      },
      {
        end_date: {
          $lte: new Date().toISOString(),
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```